# Why won't my code play a tone for my arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, audio

I have the following code that I use to try to play a melody on my Arduino, but there is no melody just a tapping noise.

I am using the built in [`tone()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/) function to play on a speaker/buzzer.

I know my hardware setup is correct because running [sample code online](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ToneMelody?from=Tutorial.Tone) plays a nice melody.

```
void setup() { }
void loop() {

    noTone(6);
  // C7 in eighth
    tone(6, 2093, 250); delay(250);
    noTone(6);
    //B7 in eighth
    tone(6, 3951, 250); delay(250);
    noTone(6);    
    //G7 in fourth
    tone(6, 3136, 500); delay(500);
    noTone(6);
    //G7 in eighth
    tone(6, 3136, 250); delay(250);
    noTone(6);
    //F7 in eighth
    tone(6, 2794, 250); delay(250);
    noTone(6);
    //E7 in eighth 
    tone(6, 2637, 250); delay(250);
    noTone(6);
    //E7 in fourth
    tone(6, 2637, 500); delay(500);
    noTone(6);
    //G7 in eighth
    tone(6, 3136, 250); delay(250);
    noTone(6);
    //G7 in halves
    tone(6, 3136, 1000); delay(1000);
    noTone(6);
    //C6 in fourth
    tone(6, 1047, 500); delay(500);
    noTone(6);
    //B6 in eighth
    tone(6, 1976, 250); delay(250);
    noTone(6);
    //G6 in eighth
    tone(6, 1566, 250); delay(250);
    noTone(6);
    //C6 in eighth
    tone(6, 1047, 250); delay(250);
    noTone(6);

}
```

This is supposed to be the melody for poker face using the tone() function

Comment: you don't need noTone if you start another tone.

Comment: The sample code you link to shows pin 8 as the connection, but your code shows pin 6. If your hardware setup is "Correct" because the sample code works, you have to look at what is then different between your code and the sample code that is known to work.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded it, and it works for me.

Hmmm.   Try downloading the other examples again, just to make sure you haven't moved a jumper.

Another way to check this out is to cut down the program to one or two lines, and see if that does or doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What is the speaker/buzzer you are connecting to? It may need more current then the pin can support (a few tens of mA, absolute max of 40mA to prevent damaging the pin).